# How to modify the records

Tags: database, vb6, ado

Using VB6

I am saving the user the entry in the database.

Code.

```
rst.Open "SELECT * FROM ShiftMaster WHERE Shift_Code = '" & Trim(txtCode.Text) & "'", adoPunching, adOpenDynamic, adLockBatchOptimistic
    If (rst.BOF And rst.EOF) Then
        rst.AddNew
    End If


    rst!Shift_Code = "" & txtCode.Text
    rst!Shift_Name = "" & txtName.Text
    rst!Start_Time = "" & Format(dtpFrom.Value, "HH:mm")
    rst!End_Time = "" & Format(dtpTo.Value, "HH:mm")
    rst.UpdateBatch
    rst.Requery
    rst.Close
    MsgBox "Data successfully saved.", vbInformation
    lvdvendor
```

The above code is working for saving, but if the user enter the same txtcode means it should modify the records, it should add new rows.

For Example

ID Value

001 200

If the user enter the same id in the textbox like 001 and user changed the value like 500 means it should chand only the value, It should add one more row with same id.

How to do this.

Need VB6 Code Help

Comment: You may want to sanitise the input to your queries. Someone putting ' in the code will break things very nicely.

Comment: I've added some suitable tags to your question, if you're not using ADO, can you update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you know which record you are poining to after doing the query? The answer is that you don't so you need to move to the first record:

```
rst.movefirst
'then add new if no records exist:
If (rst.BOF And rst.EOF) Then
    rst.AddNew
End If
```

One point to note though is that you may return more than one record when you do your query so in this way it will only update the first one it finds. You way want to consider using `TOP 1 *` so ensure you only retrieve 1 or 0 records.